# Padding around modeline text?

Tags: faces, mode-line

The text in my modeline fits exactly in the modeline, I would like to have some more padding above and below the text, couldn't find an option for it and don't know much about text properties in Emacs. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can customize the `:box` attribute of the `mode-line-face`. From the documentation (<kbd>C-h</kbd>`set-face-attribute`<kbd>RET</kbd>

> `:box'
>
> VALUE specifies whether characters in FACE should have a box drawn
>   around them.  If VALUE is nil, explicitly don't draw boxes.  If VALUE
>   is t, draw a box with lines of width 1 in the foreground color of the
>   face.  If VALUE is a string, the string must be a color name, and the
>   box is drawn in that color with a line width of 1.  Otherwise, VALUE
>   must be a property list of the form `(:line-width WIDTH :color COLOR
>   :style STYLE)'.  If a keyword/value pair is missing from the property
>   list, a default value will be used for the value, as specified below. 
>   WIDTH specifies the width of the lines to draw; it defaults to 1.

So that following should give you the padding you want

```el
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
                    :box '(:line-width 3))
```

You might also want to give a certain background to the box, you can do that by specifying the `:color` property to the `:box` property something like below

```el
(set-face-attribute 'mode-line nil
                :box '(:line-width 6 :color "gray20"))
```

Credits: I got this trick from Amit Patel's [blog](http://amitp.blogspot.in/2011/08/emacs-custom-mode-line.html)

Comment: Your welcome, updated the answer to mention the way to specify the color for the box

Comment: Thanks, just figured it out(by reading the documentation excerpt you provided) and deleted my previous comment before I noticed your edit.

Answer (score 5):

A hacky solution could consist in adding a tall zero-width character at the beginning of your mode-line. Something like:

```elisp
(setq-default mode-line-format
              (cons (propertize "\u200b" 'display '((raise -0.5) (height 2))) mode-line-format))
```

Comment: Shows no effect in my mode-line...

Comment: Are you using emacs in GUI mode (as opposed to `emacs -nw` in a terminal)? Does it have no effect at all or only a partial effect (in one of the buffers, for example)?

Comment: I edited the answer to fix a problem with buffer-local value (the previous solution worked only for one buffer).

Comment: It works now thanks, it was a problem with another manual mode-line update config which interfered with your solution.